# How to parse nested JSON object in java

Tags: java, json

Here is the sample JSON string. I want to parse this nested JSON object even though nested object have the same name. Some time we may have multiple levels of the nested objects. I tired with Jackson nested objects parsing but that did not work for me. After parsing the object, i want to convert that into a different format.Please help me in parsing this JSON. Thanks in advance.

```
 {
      "operator": "and",
      "predicates": [
        {
          "operator": "and",
          "predicates": [
            {
              "columnName": "userName",
              "datatype": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operand": "equal",
              "value": "xxxx"
            },
            {
              "columnName": "Age",
              "datatype": "number",
              "input": "number",
              "operand": "greater_or_equal",
              "value": "21"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "operator": "and",
          "predicates": [
            {
              "columnName": "userName",
              "datatype": "string",
              "input": "text",
              "operand": "not_equal",
              "value": "nnn"
            },
            {
              "columnName": "Birthday",
              "datatype": "date",
              "input": "date_picker",
              "operand": "in",
              "value": "2020-07-23,2020-07-24"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

below is the code in java

```
import java.util.Map;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Predicates {
    
    private String columnName;
    private String datatype;
    private String input;
    private String operator;
    private String value;
    private String operand;
    
    /**
     * 
     */
    
    private List<Predicates> predicates;
    
    @JsonProperty("predicates")
    private void unpackNested(Map<String,Object> predicates) {
        this.columnName = (String)predicates.get("columnName");
        this.datatype = (String)predicates.get("datatype");
        this.input = (String)predicates.get("input");
        this.operator = (String)predicates.get("operator");
        this.value = (String)predicates.get("value");
        this.operand = (String)predicates.get("operand");
    }
    
    
    public String getColumnName() {
        return columnName;
    }
    public void setColumnName(String columnName) {
        this.columnName = columnName;
    }
    public String getDatatype() {
        return datatype;
    }
    public void setDatatype(String datatype) {
        this.datatype = datatype;
    }
    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }
    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }
    public String getOperator() {
        return operator;
    }
    public void setOperator(String operator) {
        this.operator = operator;
    }
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getOperand() {
        return operand;
    }

    public void setOperand(String operand) {
        this.operand = operand;
    }
    public List<Predicates> getPredicates() {
        return predicates;
    }
    public void setPredicates(List<Predicates> predicates) {
        this.predicates = predicates;
    }
}
```

Parsing

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Predicates pr = mapper.readValue(json, Predicates.class);
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? <https://www.baeldung.com/java-json> gives a nice overview including examples for several popular JSON libraries.

Comment: @Turing85 - I have tried with the Jackson libraries but that did not work.

Comment: Tell us more about the error message when you say "that did not work".

Comment: Maybe you should remove the `JsonProperty` annotation.

Comment: @taylorswiftfan - I did not get any error messages as i have written this one.

mapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve with your `unpackNested` method. Jackson can already bind properties from your JSON to your objects and handles recursive properties just fine.

I simply removed your `unpackNested` method and ran your code on your provided input:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Predicates pr = mapper.readValue(json, Predicates.class);
```

The object `pr` contains the full json including the nested child predicates. (I ran the code with [jackson databind 2.11.2](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/2.11.2)).

If your properties are not auto-detected, annotate your getters with `@JsonProperty`:

```java
class Predicate {
  // ..snip..

  @JsonProperty("input")
  public String getInput() {
    return input;
  }

  @JsonProperty("predicates")
  public List<Predicates> getPredicates() {
    return predicates;
  }
}
```

But apart from that, no extra steps need to be taken. Jackson can already unpack nested objects, just remove your (weird) `unpackNested` method and let Jackson do its job.

Answer (score 0):

```
private JSONObject parseBundle(Bundle appRestrictions, JSONObject jsonObject) {

    Log.i(TAG, "Restriction bundle received for parsing");
    try {
        for (String key : appRestrictions.keySet()) {
            Object rootBundle = appRestrictions.get(key);
            if (rootBundle instanceof Bundle) {
                Bundle bundle = (Bundle)rootBundle;
                JSONObject bundleJSON = new JSONObject();
                JSONObject jobj = parseBundle(bundle, bundleJSON);
                jsonObject.put(key,jobj);

            }else if (rootBundle instanceof Parcelable[]){
                Parcelable[] parcelablesArray;

               //Normal usecase
                    parcelablesArray = (Parcelable[])rootBundle;
                JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i <  parcelablesArray.length; i++) {
                    Bundle mBundle = (Bundle)parcelablesArray[i];
                    if (mBundle != null) {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
                        JSONObject jObject = parseBundle(mBundle,jsonObj);
                        jsonArray.put(jObject);
                    }
                }
                jsonObject.put(key,jsonArray);
                }

            }else if (rootBundle instanceof Boolean ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Byte ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Character ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Double ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Float ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Integer ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Long ||
                    rootBundle instanceof Short ||
                    rootBundle instanceof String){

                    jsonObject.put(key,appRestrictions.get(key));

            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```